# How to make an animation play on activity start with intent, and when finished with finish()

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an android app I'm developing, and an activity is started with this method inside another activity (via buttonclick).

```
private void showInfo(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
}
```

The animation works and it slides in from the bottom, up to the top, and the activity runs. Then I click a button in the new activity to close it, and the code is as follows:

```
ImageButton info = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        }
    });
```

And the following code for if the user presses the "back" button:

```
@Override

public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);

}
```

And finally, the code for slide_in_bottom:

```
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="300" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="100" android:startOffset="200" />
```

And slide_out_bottom:

```
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="300" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="100" android:startOffset="200" />
```

The problem is, the new activity slides in from the bottom as planned, but when I click the back button on my emulator or press the imagebutton to finish() the activity, the activity it goes back to is slid in from the bottom just like the new activity, but I want it to slide down from the top. How can I accomplish this, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.your_exit_animation_one, R.anim.your_exit_animation_two);
}

public void onBackPressed(){
   //you can do your other onBackPressed logic here..

   //Then just call finish()
   finish();
}
```

I hope this will make help for you....

Comment: That doesn't help the problem of me pressing the back button, and the back button not displaying the proper animation.

Comment: On further use, it doesn't even solve the problem at all. Same thing happens. The same animation plays when the activity starts, and when I call finish(); but I want the exit animation played.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my in from top code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

Change to how you need. In your current code you're starting the animation from 0 which is where it actually sits, you need to start it from -100 which is above the screen whereas 100 is below.

Also in onBackPressed just call like this:

```
// handle hardware back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.lefttocenter, R.anim.centertoright);

    }
```